# Confusion over dense level sets of the Takagi function

Tags: continuity, fractals, cantor-set, dense-subspaces

I was told that the Takagi function, $T:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is continuous and has uncountable dense level sets in $[0,1]$. This has confused me for the following reason:

Suppose $L$ is a dense level set of the Takagi function. Doesn't this mean that for any point $s\in[0,1]$ I can find a convergent set of points $\{s_n\}$ in $L$ that tend to $s$? If so, doesn't continuity imply that $T(s_n)$ tends to $T(s)$. But this would imply $s\in L$ for all $s \in [0,1]$, so the whole interval is in the level set. This can't be right surely?

Please could someone explain my misunderstanding?

Comment: It's hard to be certain but the person might have meant the following: If we let $S$ denote the set of all $y\in[0,1]$ such that the level set $T(x)=y$ is uncountable, then $S$ is dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Right... so am I right in thinking there isn't a single level set (for a single $y$) that is dense then?

Comment: Well, there is no $y$ such that the level set $T(x)=y$ is dense in the unit interval. There are $y$ values such that the level set is an uncountable set that's dense in *itself*, though - which is rather unusual. Furthermore, the set of all those $y$ values is, I believe, dense in $[0,1]$. Perhaps, that's what they meant?